# Get only first match in Regex

Tags: regex

Given this string: `hello"C07","73"` (quotes included) I want to get "C07". I'm using `(?:hello)|(?<=")(?<screen>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(?=")` to try to do this. However, it consistently matches "73" as well. I've tried `...0-9]+){1}...`, but that doesn't work either. I must be misunderstanding how this is supposed to work, but I can't figure out any other way.

How can I get just the first set of characters between quotes?

EDIT: Here's [a link](https://regex101.com/r/wU3hT2/65) to show my problem.

EDIT: Ok, here's exactly what I'm trying to do:

Basically, what I'm trying to get is this: 1) a positive match on "hello", 2) a group named "screen" with, in this case, "C07" in it and 3) a group named "format" with, in this case, "73" in it.

Both the "C07" and "73" will vary. "hello" will always be the same. There may or may not be an extra comma between "hello" and the first double-quote.

Comment: What about `^[^"]*"[^"]+"`

Comment: If you know that the substring you want starts with a letter, write your pattern to describe it.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte It can be only letters, only numbers or a mixture.

Comment: So what's the problem with 73? It's a number.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Whether it's a letter or number isn't what I care about, though. I just want the first match, and that's the second match.

Comment: In this case, add the language (or tool) tag you use, to choose the appropriate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you initial question of how to stop after the first match either removing the global search, or searching from the start of the string would accomplish that.

For the latter question you can name your groups and just keep extending the pattern throughout the line(s).

```
hello"(?<screen>[^"]+)","(?<format>[^"]+)"
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/PBXe8l/1

Comment: Yep, sorry about the multiple questions. TIL it's not safe to try to isolate part of a regex problem.

Comment: Yes, that is true. A regex question with the language you want to match it in and a full example would bring you a lot closer/faster to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your [regex example](https://regex101.com/r/wU3hT2/63), why not:

```
^(?:hello)"([a-zA-Z\d]+)"
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5pC1ao/1/)